# dplyr::separate based on "-", but not all ocurrences of it

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I need some help to use `dplyr::separate` to separate column `value` in the data below.

```
  data.frame(
    var = c("V0001", "V0001", "V0001", "V0001", "V0001"),
    value = c(
      "11- Rondônia",
      "12- Acre",
      "13- Amazonas",
      "14- Roraima",
      'A relação de códigos encontra-se no arquivo:'
    )
  )
```

I want to have as a result something like the data below - Note that the separation must be done based on "-". However, I can't simply type `sep = "-"` due to the the word "encontra-se" on the last row. Hence, the separation must be done on "-" that follow a number. I've tried using a regex to do so, but then the resulting df was also omitting the preceding number.

```
 var v1                                           v2
1 V0001 11                                     Rondônia
2 V0001 12                                         Acre
3 V0001 13                                     Amazonas
4 V0001 14                                      Roraima
5 V0001 NA A relação de códigos encontra-se no arquivo:
```

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `extract`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  extract(value, c("v1", "v2"), '(?:(.*\\d)-)? ?(.+)')
    var v1                                           v2
1 V0001 11                                     Rondônia
2 V0001 12                                         Acre
3 V0001 13                                     Amazonas
4 V0001 14                                      Roraima
5 V0001    A relação de códigos encontra-se no arquivo:
```

Comment: thank you! It may become a problem, but the v2 entry on the last row missed the 'A' of the beginning of the sentence. Can it be fixed?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito definitely. CHECK THE EDIT

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but there may be cases in which there is whitespace between the number and the hyphen. I've tried fixing this using ```'(?:(.*\\d)\\s+-)? (.+)'```. This fixed this specific issue, but messed up the previous ones. How could I tweak it to work?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito use `'(?:(.*\\d)\\s*-)? (.+)'`

Answer (score 0):

We could use trimws which trims the indicated characters off the ends.  The first trimws trims off the the non-digits, \D, since the first field contains only digits and the second trims off the digits 0-9 as well as space and minus off the ends.

```
d %>% 
  mutate(V1 = trimws(value, white = "\\D"), 
         V2 = trimws(value, white = "[0-9 -]"))
```